# How to find if any word in a column matches any word from another column by row in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I am trying to see if any word from colA is contained in colB in a python dataframe.

example data

```
ColA                    ColB            Match
this is some text       some text       TRUE
some more text          more            TRUE
another line text       nothing to see  FALSE
my final line           dog cats goats  FALSE
```

desc split string, emp split string 
if any word in emp = any word in desc then true else false

something like...

```
df['Match'] = df['colA'].str.split().apply(lambda x: 'true' if any x in df['ColB'].str.split() else 'false')
```

thx

Comment: `[j in i for i, j in zip(df.ColA,df.ColB)]`

Answer (score 3):

You can use apply on the whole row, like this:

```
df.apply(lambda x: np.any([word in x.ColB.split(' ') for word in x.ColA.split(' ')]),axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe using `issubset`

```
[set(y).issubset(set(x)) for x , y  in zip(df.ColA.str.split(),df.ColB.str.split())]
Out[57]: [True, True, False, False]
```

If we need only on match

```
[len(list(set(x) & set(y)))>0 for x , y  in zip(df.ColA.str.split(),df.ColB.str.split())]
Out[61]: [True, True, False, False]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension with `zip` and a custom function:

```
def find_words(words, val):
    val_split = val.split()
    return any(x in val_split for x in words.split())

df['Match'] = [find_words(a, b) for a, b in zip(df['ColA'], df['ColB'])]
```